# Storing Textbox values into Database

Tags: c#, database, textbox, panel

I am doing a crossword puzzle and i have 100 text boxes in a panel like this :
[image]

Every text box have an id of 00 - 99 since there is 100 of it .

[image]

First Row will have an id `00-09` , 2nd row will have an id of `10-19` and so on.

When user types something in some text box will be `null` and some text box will have values in it. How do I save values from a text box of a certain id to a database? For example the above image, `HELP`, text box id of `22` will have the value `H` , id of `23` will have the value of `E` , id of `24` will have value of `L` , id of `25` will have value of `P`.

I don't want to save the `null` values of the text box , I want to save values of the textboxes which are not `null`. I also need to take into account their textbox ids so that when I populate them back, I just have to insert them through ID .

I am new to C# , appreciate any help/advise/solutions on this.

Here is my code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //hw.Write("<table>");
    for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
    {
        //hw.Write("<tr>");
        for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
        {
            TextBox tb = new TextBox();
            tb.MaxLength = (1);
            tb.Width = Unit.Pixel(40);
            tb.Height = Unit.Pixel(40);
            tb.ID = i.ToString() + j.ToString(); // giving each textbox a different id  00-99 
            Panel1.Controls.Add(tb); 
        }
        Literal lc = new Literal();
        lc.Text = "<br />";
        Panel1.Controls.Add(lc);
    }
}

protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (Control control in Panel1.Controls)
    {
        var textBox = control as TextBox;   
        if (textBox != null)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
            {
                textBox.Style["visibility"] = "hidden";
            }
            // textBox.Enabled = false;
            textBox.Text = "";
        }
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The proper way to do this is to wrap these textboxes inside a Repeater or Datalist controls. You can ready about these controls from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479015.aspx). This way when number of rows increase you will not have to change to your loop or hard-coded values.

As for your question to store values for a given Id, you can define row# and col# in your database and sort on row# and col#, this should work.

Comment: I think we are talking about the webforms here, aren't we? DataList model has not changed in years, hence it doesn't make any different

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to make a 2D array (or `List`) of your TextBoxes. In where you create your TextBoxes:

```
List<List<TextBox>> textBoxList = new List<List<TextBox>>();
for (int i = 0; i <= 9; i++)
{
    List<TextBox> textBoxRow = new List<TextBox>(); //this could be columns, not sure
    for (int j = 0; j <= 9; j++)
    {
        TextBox tb = new TextBox();
        ....
        textBoxRow.Add(tb);
    }
    ...
    textBoxList.Add(textBoxRow);
}
```

Now you can read/write to those array entries, such as:

```
string readValue = textBoxList[2][5].Text;
textBoxList[1][7].Text = "asdf";
```