# C# entity framework storing values returns null exception

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, crud

Here is my code :

```
        protected void btnShow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

      foreach (Control control in Panel1.Controls)
        {
            var textBox = control as TextBox;   
            if (textBox != null)
            {
                if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(textBox.Text))
                {

                textBox.Style["visibility"] = "hidden";
                }

               // textBox.Enabled = false;

                var id = from t in textBox.Text
                           where t != null
                           select textBox.ID;

                var text = from t in textBox.Text
                           where t != null
                           select t;

                foreach (var x in id)
                {
                    Model.crossword insert = new Model.crossword();
                    insert.TextBoxID = x;                      
                    daoCrossword.Insert(insert);
                }

                foreach (var a in text)
                {
                    Model.crossword insert = new Model.crossword();
                    insert.TextBoxValue = a.ToString();
                    daoCrossword.Insert(insert);
                }
                 daoCrossword.Save();                   
            }            
        }
    }
```

daoCrossword is a class file which have CRUD codes in it , i am using EF to do this , i am new to this , it gives me an error : System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

CRUD class file (partial) :

```
  public void Insert(Model.crossword exe)
    {
        context.crosswords.AddObject(exe);
    }
public void Save()
    {
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Comment: What line are you getting the error at?  Have you tried debugging?  What values do your variables contain at the time of the error?

Comment: i did debug , x and a contains values , the error lines in daoCrossword.Save(); and context.crosswords.AddObject(exe); which is in my CRUD class file

Comment: i have edited on top to include my class file

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what you think you're doing with these two statements, but it's probably not what you think it is.

```
var id = from t in textBox.Text
         where t != null
         select textBox.ID;

var text = from t in textBox.Text
           where t != null
           select t;
```

Then your foreach statements really make no sense because you will only ever have one item in the collections.  It seems like you're trying to only save the data if there is something in the textbox, for which you should probably just do a simple if statement.

Next, you create new crossword objects in each foreach, but you only assign an id in one, and text in the other.. this is also probably not what you want.  More than likely, you just want to do this:

```
if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(textbox.Text))
{
    Model.crossword insert = new Model.crossword();
    insert.TextBoxID = textbox.ID;                      
    insert.TextBoxValue = textbox.Text;
    daoCrossword.Insert(insert);
}
```

Comment: i have many text boxes , and the 2 linq statements is to get the values of the textbox and the id of the textbox , because i am going to save them into database

Comment: @user2376998 - Yes, and your foreach on the controls object gets all those textboxes.  the linq statements are unnecessary and don't do what you think they do.  As written, they only operate on a single textbox control.

Comment: Ahhh ok that foreach controls . but i tried your codes , it still gives me the same error

Comment: @user2376998 - Are you sure that daoCrossword and context are not null?

Comment: i am sure the class file codes are good but the problem lies in textBox.ID and textBox.Text , they seems to have null value when i debug

Comment: here is my full code and what i am trying to do : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17267080/storing-textbox-values-into-database